# How to ensure one radio form does not check another radio form

Tags: html, css

I've found a pure CSS star rating system however with the given code I can only use one star system per page. I've tried changing the class names but unfortunately the second star rating form checks the first star rating form when pressed. Is there any way around this?

```
.rating { 
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating > input { display: none; } 
.rating > label:before { 
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating > .half:before { 
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating > label { 
  color: #ddd; 
 float: right; 
}

/***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.rating > input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  } /* hover previous stars in list */

.rating > input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when changing rating */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current selection */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }
```

HTML

```
<form class="form-class" id="starform">               
   <fieldset class="rating">
         <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2"/>
         <label class="full" for="star2" title="2 stars"></label>

         <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1"/> 
         <label class="full" for="star1" title="1 star"></label>
   </fieldset>
</form>

<form class="form-class" id="starformtwo">               
       <fieldset class="ratingtwo">
             <input type="radio" id="star2-2" name="ratingtwo" value="2"/>
             <label class="full" for="star2-2" title="2 stars"></label>

             <input type="radio" id="star1-2" name="ratingtwo" value="1"/> 
             <label class="full" for="star1-2" title="1 star"></label>
       </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: All your CSS selectors refer to `ratings` but none of your elements have that class

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this ?

```css
.ratings { 
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.ratings > input { display: none; } 
.ratings > label:before { 
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.ratings > .half:before { 
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.ratings > label { 
  color: #ddd; 
 float: right; 
}

/***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.ratings > input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
.ratings:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
.ratings:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  } /* hover previous stars in list */

.ratings > input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when changing rating */
.ratings > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.ratings > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current selection */
.ratings > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }

.ratingtwo { 
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.ratingtwo > input { display: none; } 
.ratingtwo > label:before { 
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.ratingtwo > .half:before { 
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.ratingtwo > label { 
  color: #ddd; 
 float: right; 
}

/***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.ratingtwo > input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
.ratingtwo:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
.ratingtwo:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  } /* hover previous stars in list */

.ratingstwo > input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when changing rating */
.ratingstwo > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.ratingtwo > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current selection */
.ratingtwo > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-class" id="starform">               
   <fieldset class="ratings">
         <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2"/>
         <label class="full" for="star2" title="2 stars"></label>

         <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1"/> 
         <label class="full" for="star1" title="1 star"></label>
   </fieldset>
</form>

<form class="form-class" id="starformtwo">               
       <fieldset class="ratingtwo">
             <input type="radio" id="star2-2" name="ratingtwo" value="2"/>
             <label class="full" for="star2-2" title="2 stars"></label>

             <input type="radio" id="star1-2" name="ratingtwo" value="1"/> 
             <label class="full" for="star1-2" title="1 star"></label>
       </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Or you can go to jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rnpow2yz/

Hope this code work.

Comment: Oddly I did the same but it did not work. Thanks. I suppose I would need to use SASS to keep it DRY

Comment: it didn't work? really? i tested in jsfiddle, it works as well.